# Undefined index error in php although i defined it.why?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php so please guide and don't make it duplicate because i can't get solution from previous solutions.My php code is given below

```
 <?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
 $city  = $_GET['city'];
 $town  = $_GET['town'];
//$skills=$_POST['skills'];
require_once('DbConnect.php'); 
 //Creating sql query
 $sql = "SELECT FROM employees where city='".$city."' and town='".$town."'";
 
 //getting result 
 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 
 //creating a blank array 
 $result = array();
 
 //looping through all the records fetched
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
 
 //Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
 array_push($result,array(
 "name"=>$row['name'],
 "phone"=>$row['phone'],
 "skills"=>$row['skills']
 ));
 }
 
 //Displaying the array in json format 
 echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
 
 mysqli_close($con);
 }
 ?>
```

**ERROR**

> Notice: Undefined index: city in C:\xampp\htdocs\getServices\employeesInfo.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined index: town in C:\xampp\htdocs\getServices\employeesInfo.php on line 4
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\getServices\employeesInfo.php on line 17
> {"result":[]}

Comment: Change your SQL query to `$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees ...`

Comment: Whats the URL or form? You are open to SQL injections, parameterize. Just checking the request method isnt enough.

Comment: Besides the obvious SQL injection issues, if there are no get vars for city or town defined in your URL, then you will get this error

Comment: Use `die` method with `$_GET` to see the contents and verify if city & town keys are present.

Comment: @DeepanshSachdeva OP will need `print_r` as well, `die` alone cant print array contents.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul thanks but i am still getting Undefined index error on"city & town".please explain

Comment: Also would you ever have a city and town; aren't those the same thing, just different government structures?

Comment: See @chris85's [comment there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46143287/undefined-index-error-in-php-although-i-defined-it-why?noredirect=1#comment79248357_46143287). Also, do `var_dump($_GET);` and see what you have in there.

Comment: You're already using an API that supports **prepared statements** with bounded variable input, you should utilize parameterized queries with placeholders (prepared statements) to protect your database against [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)!
 Get started with [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) and [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select one or more columns, for example by doing *select all* `SELECT * FROM..`, the query would look like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees where city='".$city."' and town='".$town."'";
```

**Update_Code:**

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && !empty($_GET['city']) && !empty($_GET['town'])){

 $city  = $_GET['city'];
 $town  = $_GET['town'];

//$skills=$_POST['skills'];
require_once('DbConnect.php'); 

 //Creating sql query 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM employees where city='".$city."' and town='".$town."'";

 //getting result 
 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 //creating a blank array 
 $result = array();

 //looping through all the records fetched
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

 //Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
 array_push($result,array(
 "name"=>$row['name'],
 "phone"=>$row['phone'],
 "skills"=>$row['skills']
 ));
 }

 //Displaying the array in json format 
 echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

 mysqli_close($con);
 }
 else{

 $message = " Fill all the details First";

 }

if(isset($message) && !empty($message) ){

echo "$message";
}

?>
```